# Problems with SOAP request

Tags: web-services, soap, siebel, sap-basis

I am trying to integrate Siebel CRM with SAP system via...
The problem is : the SOAP request that siebel is generating is giving me an error while if I use SOAP UI to generate the SOAP request, it is working fine. Following are the error mesages and SOAP requests generated

Error from siebel SOAP request :

> CX_ST_MATCH_ELEMENT:.System expected element 'PiCopyreference'".(SBL-EAI-04308)

Unsuccessful Siebel generated SOAP Request:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <CustomerCreatefromdata1 xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
            <PiCompanydata xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style"></PiCompanydata>
            <PiCopyreference xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
                <Salesorg xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">0001</Salesorg>
                <DistrChan xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">01</DistrChan>
                <Division xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">01</Division>
                <RefCustmr xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">0000000011</RefCustmr>
            </PiCopyreference>
            <PiOptCompanydata xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style"></PiOptCompanydata>
            <PiOptPersonaldata xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
                <Transpzone xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">0000000001</Transpzone>
            </PiOptPersonaldata>
            <PiPersonaldata xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
                <TitleP xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">MR</TitleP>
                <Firstname xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">FirstN</Firstname>
                <Lastname xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">lastN</Lastname>
                <City xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">SomeCity</City>
                <PostlCod1 xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">7866</PostlCod1>
                <Country xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">AT</Country>
                <LanguP xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">E</LanguP>
                <Currency xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">INR</Currency>
            </PiPersonaldata>
        </CustomerCreatefromdata1>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Successfull SOAP UI generated request :-

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <urn:CustomerCreatefromdata1>
            <PiCompanydata/>
            <PiCopyreference>
                <Salesorg>0001</Salesorg>
                <DistrChan>01</DistrChan>
                <Division>01</Division>
                <RefCustmr>0000000011</RefCustmr>
            </PiCopyreference>
            <PiOptCompanydata/>
            <PiOptPersonaldata>
                <Transpzone>0000000001</Transpzone>
            </PiOptPersonaldata>
            <PiPersonaldata>
                <TitleP>MR</TitleP>
                <Firstname>FirstN</Firstname>
                <Lastname>lastN</Lastname>
                <City>SomeCity</City>
                <PostlCod1>7866</PostlCod1>
                <Country>AT</Country>
                <LanguP>E</LanguP>
                <Currency>INR</Currency>
            </PiPersonaldata>
        </urn:CustomerCreatefromdata1>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Also in siebel i'm generating the SOAP request using workflows(no scripting involved).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be namespace issue. In the Siebel external IO, you could try inactivating all the user properties for namespace at ICField level.

Comment: thanks for the tip ranjith... i tried this and now the xmlns property is not coming in any tag except CustomerCreatefromdata1 ... but still the problem is same, getting the same error message. Even when i manually remove the xmlns property from CustomerCreatefromdata1 tag there is no change.

Comment: got it working...
Deactivating the XMLTAGNAMESPACE field just made the child elemets inherit the namespace from the parent while keeping them active and just deleting the Value col. made it work.